# Control order of components added from page design on the assigned page

Tags: sxa, presentation

I have some pages previously created with some components added to the main placeholder. Then I created a new page design and partial design on which I added a new component to the main placeholder as well. My problem is that when I assign the new page design to the pages, I find the new component rendered from the page design displayed first and then the components that were manually added on the page. However, I need the component from the partial design to be displayed after the components already on the pages.

Is there a way to control the order of the component added from the partial design to be added at the bottom of the page when there are already other components on the page layout?

Answer (score 0):

tl/dr: No you can't control that order, its just how the pages are composed together. You need to use containers in your page design to provide locations for components to be added at the page level. This will then give your editors control over the order of the components on the page.